# how to create 32bit depth pixmap with XQuartz (or X11.app) and XMingw

Tags: macos, x11

I'm trying to use ARGB pixmaps with XRender under mac and windows, but both servers does not seem to have 32 bit visuals.

- I don't need to have 32bit depth window. I just need server-side pixmap
- Render extension is available and server-side render compositing is working just fine (using render pictures with transparency but without pixmap, e.i gradients)
- according to [Keith Packard comment](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88662#c2) server with Render extension must provide 32bit depth visual
- during connection handshake server returns list of 32 bit visuals, but the list is empty
- according to x11 protocol specification for CreatePixmap request: *The depth must be one of the
  depths supported by the root of the specified drawable (or a Value error results)*

If server implementation is correct, what is the simplest possible way to create 32bit depth pixmap using XQuartz (or X11.app) or using windows+XMingw?

If X server is broken, is there any way to work around (create render picture using 24 bit pixmap and attach alpha channel to it?)

**edit**: I [can create pixmap](https://gist.github.com/2583100), but now having problem uploading buffer to it using XPutImage.

I'm using my own [X client library](https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11), example with PutImage is [here](https://gist.github.com/2583233). I'll try to convert to C/XLib with XCreateImage/XPutImage

Comment: `xdpyinfo` tells me it supports 32-bit pixmaps.

Comment: this is the output of my xdpyinfo: https://gist.github.com/2582961 . There is 32bit entry in the depth list for screen#0 - "depths (7):    24, 15, 1, 4, 8, 16, 32" but no 32bit visual in the list of visuals

Comment: Line 18 shows a 32-bit depth among supported pixmap formats.

Comment: it seems that I can actually create pixmap (probably all my previous errors were caused by incompatible picture format or compositing. Simple test: https://gist.github.com/2583100

Comment: I can create pixmap, but now get "Match Error" when trying to use PutImage with width x height x 32bit buffer